# Can't find string terminator "str" anywhere before EOF

Tags: perl, string, syntax, heredoc

Why I get this error?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = <<str; 
88087   23/11/2010 
35192   25/07/2010 
B3J 5X9 17/08/2011 
C8U 5L6 16/08/2011 
F4Q 3B4 17/10/2010 
D3X 9P4 11/05/2010 
O7L 6Z8 28/02/2010 
W8L 9P2 05/09/2010 
str 

print $str;

my @arr = split/\n/,$str;
foreach (@arr) {
        my @tmp = split/\t/;
        print "$tmp[1]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should not have a space here:

```
str 
   ^
```

The heredoc terminator should be on a line by itself and should not have *anything* (not even *space*) surrounding it.

Comment: May I recommend people configure their editor to show whitespace at end-of-line, as it does help catching these kind of bugs

Answer (score 1):

Or Better Use Eclipse Perl Integration plug-in or Padre for editing your perl code.
It shows real-time syntax related errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) to get more verbose help on warning messages:

> Can't find string terminator "str"
>   anywhere before EOF
>       (F) Perl strings can stretch over multiple lines.  This message means
>       that the closing delimiter was omitted.  Because bracketed quotes
>   count
>       nesting levels, the following is missing its final parenthesis:
>
> ```
>     print q(The character '(' starts a side comment.);
> ```
>
> **>     If you're getting this error from a here-document, you may have included
>       unseen whitespace before or after your closing tag. A good programmer's
>       editor will have a way to help you find these characters.**
>
> ```
>  Uncaught exception from user code:
> ```
>
> Can't find string terminator "str" anywhere before EOF